# How to make a hidden "Exit" button in java netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, button

I want to create a hidden button in netbeans. Suppose if I click a Next button then a new "Exit" button  will be appear in the same jFrame. Until I click the Next button the Exit button will not be shown. So how to make it?  I mean how to make a button which is by-default in .setVisible(false) in netbeans?

Please help me out about this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already seem to know the proper method I assume you doubt is about Netbeans operation.

Right click in the method and select "*Customize Code*".

Then you'll have the chance to add the proper code after the button creation.

Comment: Thank you so much Madth. You solved my problem. Its working 100%

Answer (score 4):

Use `JButton.setVisible(false);` right after you create the button.

Comment: I have to write your line line in generated code in netbeans. NetBeans is not allowing me to do that. So where to write it?